# How do I get the styler package to split function arguments across multiple lines?

Tags: r, tidyverse

how do I make styler split function arguments across multiple lines?

Ex:

```
styler::style_text("mutate(a = case_when(a == 1L ~ \"1\", a == 2L ~ \"2\", a < 10 ~ \"3+\", TRUE ~ \"ERROR\"), b = 2)")
#> mutate(a = case_when(a == 1L ~ "1", a == 2L ~ "2", a < 10 ~ "3+", TRUE ~ "ERROR"), b = 2)
```

I'm expecting to see something more like

```
mutate(
  a = 
    case_when(
      a == 1L ~ "1", 
      a == 2L ~ "2", 
      a < 10 ~ "3+", 
      TRUE ~ "ERROR"), 
  b = 2)
```

Comment: I guess you'd need to write a specific line-breaker function. A "quick-ish" workaround would be to select your function, search for "," select all, then insert a line break with your return key. (This assumes you are using RStudio).

Comment: If you want to write the line-breaker, here the documentation for a starter: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/styler/styler.pdf

Comment: @tjebo thanks, i was hoping this functionality might have already been built into styler, but after looking through the github issues history it appears it might not.  might just have to do like you said and write my own transformer

Comment: For the record there is a long standing feature request to break lines at 80 characters, (or any limit) and we might at some point start tackling this with breaking lines in function calls according to [this](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/247#issuecomment-485481338) comment. `case_when()` is s special case again (like switch) for which we also have an issue. Please upvote if you care about it, we factor ing upvotes when prioritising work:  https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/714